# Create .tiff image with both transparency channel and alpha channel

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop, tiff, gimp, gimpfu

By setting a .tiff file "tiff:alpha" tag to either unspecified or unassociated I can have photoshop display it's alpha channel as either a premultiplied transparency or a seperate alpha channel. However if I manually edit an image through photoshop, and I manually add an alpha channel, create transparency in the R/G/B channels and then check "export transparency" during the export process. I can have both the premultiplied channel and the alpha channel. I'm however not able to do this through any processing code using either GIMP or ImageMagick. How would I go about replicating this through script/code and is it even possible?

```
exec(`gimp -i -d -f -b '(let* ((img (car (file-png-load 1 \"example.png\" \"example.png\")))
     (drawable (car (gimp-image-active-drawable img))))
     (gimp-image-select-item img 0 drawable)
     (plug-in-sel2path 0 img drawable)
     (gimp-image-insert-channel img (car (gimp-channel-new-from-component img 5 \"Alpha 1\")) 0 5)
     (gimp-image-insert-channel img (car (gimp-channel-new-from-component img 5 \"Transparency\")) 0 6)
     (file-tiff-save 1 img drawable \"output.tiff\" \"output.tiff\" 1) (gimp-quit 0))'`, {cwd: `src/images/${r}`, env:process.env}, async (error, stdout, stderr) => {                        
        im.convert([`${appDir}/images/${r}/output.tiff`, "-define", 
        "tiff:alpha=unspecified", `${appDir}/images/${r}/output2.tiff`], () => {
            //script where I save the the output image
        })
})
```

The code above is run in a node.js environment.

A relevant similar question to what i want: [How to append an alpha channel to a TIFF (or pdf) with Imagemagick (or imagick php)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69364841/how-to-append-an-alpha-channel-to-a-tiff-or-pdf-with-imagemagick-or-imagick-p)

Comment: I do not believe you can do that currently with Imagemagick

Comment: Could there possibly be another route outside of gimp/ImageMagick that might allow this?

Comment: Apparently one can do this with Imagemagick using ftxt:. See https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick/discussions/5840#discussioncomment-4291130

Comment: Funnily enough that's my threat, currently trying to use the answer they gave me there.

Answer (score 1):

#### Not with Gimp

There are two API calls to save a TIFF in Gimp:

```
(file-tiff-save run-mode image drawable filename raw-filename compression)
```

and

```
(file-tiff-save2 run-mode image drawable filename raw-filename compression save-transp-pixels)
```

As you can see, the only difference between the two is the `save-transp-pixels` argument, documented thus:

> Keep the color data masked by an alpha channel intact (do not store premultiplied components)

So it's either premultiplied or not premultiplied, but not both.